# Convert Tesnor to TensorType

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, theano, tensor

I have a `Tensor` object which I obtain from the `Keras` framework, and I need to feed it as the inputs variable into the following code:

```
T.dot(inputs[1], self.pi)
```

where `self.pi` refers to an `ndarray`.

However this throws the following error:

`Cannot convert Tensor("strided_slice_6:0", shape=(1024,), dtype=float32) to TensorType', <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`

Is there any way to convert a `Tensor` object to a `TensorType`, or is there a way I could replace the above code to be able to use a `Tensor` instead?

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/6278 ?

Comment: I'm not trying to convert a TesnorType to a TensorType, but a Tensor to a TensorType